# Symfony redirect issue on Windows computers (mostly on Chrome, sometimes Firefox)

Tags: apache, symfony, vps

This is a site developed using Symfony and is hosted on a Linux VPS. This only happens when the site does a redirect, sometimes it will not render the code and add a 0 at the top of the page. I've attached a screenshot of what gets displayed. We tried installing the site on a cloud server and this issue does not occur.

One of the Pages this happens on is the Login page. If you are on a Windows computer, you can try to login with username *testuser* and password *testuser* and the error will sometimes get generated because of the redirect on the page.

The code below is the action in the controller to create new job description (http://hr-tool.inshpo.org/description/new). After the form is submitted successfully, it redirects to another page.

```
/**
* Creates a new Description entity.
*
 * @Route("/new", name="description_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $description = new Description();
    $description->setCountry($this->getUser()->getCountry());
    $description->setUser($this->getUser());
    $form = $this->createForm('PositionBundle\Form\DescriptionType', $description);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $description->setPickedType($description->getMainPosition()->getType());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($description);
        $em->flush();

        $points = $em->getRepository('PositionBundle:Point')->findAll();
        $positions = $em->getRepository('PositionBundle:Position')->findBy(['level'=>$description->getMainPosition()->getLevel(),'type'=>$description->getPickedType()],['point'=>'ASC']);

        for ($i = 0 ; $i< count($points); $i++){
            $customPoint = new CustomPoint();
            $customPoint->setPoint($points[$i]);
            $customPoint->setDescription($description);
            $customPoint->setPickedPosition($positions[$i]);
            $em->persist($customPoint);
        }

        $customDuty = new CustomDuty();
        $activities = $em->getRepository('PositionBundle:Activity')->findAll();
        $customDuty->setDutyDescription($this->get('libs.entities_crawlers')->getDutiesTextarea($activities,$description->getPickedType()));
        $customDuty->setDescription($description);
        $em->persist($customDuty);

        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('description_my_tabs', array('id' => $description->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('description/new.html.twig', array(
    'description' => $description,
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPrM7.jpg)

Comment: There's not enough information shown here. Please post some of your controller code.

Comment: Hey @AlvinBunk, I updated the post. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: just tested from windows... no error was thrown for me

Comment: You might need to do some more debugging. I tried logging in to the above link a few times. It worked twice on two different browsers, but then gave me a message like "you can't access the content". The other thing I'm thinking is it could be a permission or maybe mod_rewrite with Apache. Can you post the http.conf details (only the important parts)? Also check your logs in `var/logs`.